# Issue while moving from current activity to previous activity using getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have few activities and I want to move current activity to previous, like A->B->C-D, here i want to go to D->c->B->A, I have added respective parent activity name in manifest for all activities but when i press arrow in activity D its goes to activity A directly, if i backpress then it is coming to C activity, 
How to to it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may override your `onOptionsItemSelected`-method to achieve the same behaviour in both cases...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done this, i have some icons in menu and moving to respective activities with their id. but not working fine in backbutton click

Comment: I am able to move to A from B works fine, I want to go to B from C which is taking me to A directly but B activity is not killed, its opening when I press back again

Comment: How do you navigate forward and backward between your activities, please provide some code

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); I have added it in B gave parent in manifest as A, same 2 lines are added in C and gave parent as B ,

Comment: also add your onOptionsItemSelected method. And please put your code in your question as code is hard to read as a comment

Comment: I have not done anything else than this, someone please help how to solve this issue

Comment: Please try and add the code, I provided in my answer, to your Activity C. Restart your app and then press the back-icon in this activity and you should experience the same behavoiur as when you press the back-button on your device (You should go back from C to B...)

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.cart) {
            Intent i = new Intent(BookDetails.this, MyCartActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

Comment: This is onOptionItem method in both activites I mean B and C

Comment: if (itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
Add this to your onOptionsItemSelected in Activity C

Comment: hey sorry, not able to vote u as i dont have reputations,

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a regular proceed of your back button. You can read more about it at the [official website](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

You can set flags to your intent, if you want to get other behavior. 
[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)